# Under which conditions a solution of an ODE is analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If I'm not wrong there is a theorem that says that if the conditions for Picard's theorem are satisfied, for an ode $\dot x=f(x,t)$, then the solution of the ode is as smooth as $f$. I think I'm not wrong with this fact.

So if $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^k$ then $x(t)$ will be also $\mathcal{C}^k$. I wonder if the fact that $f$ is analytic implies also that $x$ is analytic or if there is another condition that implies so.

Comment: See G.Birkhoff/G.Rota _Ordinary Differential Equations_ (4th ed.), pp. 121-128 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is called Cauchy's theorem. If $f(x,t)$ is analytic at $(x_0,t_0)$ then there exists a unique solution analytic at the point $t_0$. The same theorem is true when you consider both $x,t\in\mathbf C$.

Your statement about the smoothness of solutions is not quite correct. You have that if $f\in C^k$ then solution is $C^{k+1}$.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the theorem? There are lot's of results with the 'Cauchy' name on it, and I don't find this particular one. A reference is also fine.

Comment: This can be considered as the simplest case of Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem.

Comment: I can't award the bounty right now. The site asks me to wait for 23 hours. But I will remember.

Comment: For the transparent proofs you can see Chapter 4 of [Teschl's book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf)

Comment: Good to know. I never heard about this theorem. But the statement was looking quite natural.