# Anti-derivative of analytic function

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the derivative of an analytic function $f$ is analytic.

Is it also true that the anti-derivative of an analytic function is also analytic?

Comment: It is so by definition.

Comment: I don't see that from the definition. What is the argument? Would that imply then that this other question has an affirmative answer?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833988/under-which-conditions-a-solution-of-an-ode-is-analytic-function

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem may help.

Comment: By definition, the antiderivative $F$ of $f$ satisfies $F'=f$, with the prime denoting the complex derivative. Also by definition, a function which has a complex derivative is analytic.

Comment: @Ambesh I missed the (real-analysis) tag. But if you know about complex analysis, then my comment is the simplest way to see this, I think. If you don't know about complex analysis, then it a consequence of the fact that if $f(x)=\sum c_n(x-a)^n$, then you can integrate term by term to get an antiderivative of $f$. This needs to be justified, though.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I think it should be justified with the dominated convergence theorem. Still the complex analysis answer is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative satisfies $F^\prime(z)=f(z)$. $f(z)$ exists. Since $F(z)$ has a complex derivative, it is analytic; hence $F(z)$ is analytic.

Comment: I can't give you credit for posting something already posted above. Sorry.

Comment: @Ambesh Therefore I made it CW.